# Angularjs : not seeing full results from promise unless console is opened

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I have a promise that returns some data. I use that data in a data grid (ng-grid, specifically). The  grid only displays a small portion of the data unless I open the console at which point it displays all of the data. Why would this happen?

Here is some code:

```
 //This returns a promise with the results of my db query
 Admin.getShipments().then(function (data) {
        $log.log('data from promise: ', data); <-- this lists 20 elements
        $scope.shipments = data;
    });

 $scope.gridOptions = {
     data: 'shipments',
     // some column definitions here... removed as not necessary
 };
```

Using the above my grid only displays 6 elements while the console log shows that there are actually 20. If I inspect element (open console) then the grid will suddenly display all 20 elements.

Why? Is the value for $scope.shipments simply not fully populated when the grid goes to retrieve it? If so, how do you work around this?

**Here is an attempt at a solution that does not work...**
I tried placing the data grid setup inside the promise "then", thinking that this would ensure that I had all of the needed data but the entire grid fails (saying the grid values are undefined) when I do this. Here is an example of that:

```
 //This fails entirely and the grid complains about undefined values
 Admin.getShipments().then(function (data) {
        $log.log('data from promise: ', data); <-- this lists 20 elements
        $scope.shipments = data;
        $scope.gridOptions = {
            data: 'shipments',
            // some column definitions here... removed as not necessary
        };
    });
```

How can I reliably get all of my retrieved data to display in this grid without having to open the console to make it appear (and why would simply opening console have such an effect?)

Comment: This is very strange. You are either doing something strange, or have hit a big bug of ng-grid (not unlikely). It would be very helpful if you could reproduce the bug in a fiddle/plunk...

Comment: I wouldn't be able to simulate the promise in a fiddle. Thing is, the log statement in my example does show the correct number of results but the grid does not (unless I open console, of course).

Answer (score 0):

after testing your code, I successfully reproduced this bug, when grid height is missing, by default the grid renders only 20 rows, after adding height, the grid rendered properly.

**Example:**

js:

```
  $http.get('largeLoad.json').success(function (data) {
     $scope.shipments=data;
  });


    $scope.gridOptions = {
        data: 'shipments'
    };
});
```

css:

```
.gridStyle{
  height:500px;
}
```

Live example: http://plnkr.co/edit/bg6NMW162qKbm6QUlINo?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for looking at it but that isn't the problem. I already have that height set and while the grid is that height it has only 6 rows showing... the rest of it is just empty. Visible (I can put a border around it and see how tall it is) but missing most of the rows that are in the data.

Comment: but as you can see , the grid showed all data, I thought that is your problem?.

Comment: No, the grid will show all data if I simply open the console. That's what's so strange... the log shows all data is present but the grid only shows a few rows. However, once I simply open the browser console, all of the rows appear.

Comment: in my example the grid shows all rows without opening the console, at least that worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely some sort of bug in ng-grid. I found this value in their code:

```
// the # of rows we want to add to the top and bottom of the rendered grid rows
var EXCESS_ROWS = 6;
```

Changing that number changes the number of elements that are displayed. So right now it's 6 and when I load the page I only see 6 records until I open console at which point they all appear. If I set it to 10 I see 10 until I open console and so on. If the number is larger than the available number of records then all records are displayed so a workaround is to simply make the number larger than the number of records you have. Obviously that's a hack but that's all I have time for right now. I'll update if I get around to actually solving the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this sounds like a buffer flush issue.  You have a call to print to the console .. I would guess that there isn't a flush to that final call unless the console is open and thus it's blocking the flush to the document.

I would take the call to the console out and see if it works.. if so then research how to force a flush of that buffer.